# Order of compound index columns results in different plan

Tags: postgresql

I have users table (1.5M rows) with `last_name`(varchar) and `status`(integer) columns. Last name are some random surnames and statuses are:

```
enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1, blocked: 2, inactive: 3, part_active: 4, disabled: 5 }
```

I want to add compound index on this. I am using Rails so basically it goes like:

```
add_index :users, [:last_name, :status]
```

I test it with simple query which is:

```
 User.where(status: 'active', last_name: 'Anderson').explain(:analyze)
```

as a result of planner I get:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=4.68..102.86 rows=25 width=108) (actual time=0.559..1.446 rows=489 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((last_name)::text = 'Anderson'::text) AND (status = 0))
   Heap Blocks: exact=484
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_users_on_last_name_and_status  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=25 width=0) (actual time=0.091..0.092 rows=489 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((last_name)::text = 'Anderson'::text) AND (status = 0))
 Planning Time: 0.133 ms
 Execution Time: 1.535 ms
```

For my surprise, when I changed the order of columns in index, I've got different (simpler) query plan:

```
add_index :users, [:status, :last_name]
```

It results with such a plan:

```
 Index Scan using index_users_on_status_and_last_name on users  (cost=0.43..103.41 rows=25 width=108) (actual time=0.065..0.755 rows=489 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((status = 0) AND ((last_name)::text = 'Anderson'::text))
 Planning Time: 0.152 ms
 Execution Time: 0.813 ms
```

My PostgreSQL version is 13.

Why I've got different results in planner because of changed order? As I understand, cardinality/selectivity of data should not affect when I use only equality matchers, it should only affect < > etc. matchers, as I checked for example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329297/optimal-order-for-creating-a-composite-index-in-postgresql-with-multiple-conditi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is probably based on the correlation between each attribute and the physical order of rows in the table.  See pg_stats.correlation for each attribute.  When the correlation of the leading column in the index is low, the planner assumes it will jumping to random parts of the table, leading to a poor IO pattern. Using a bitmap scan can partially ameliorate this, so low correlation encourages bitmap scans over ordinary index scans.

> As I understand, cardinality/selectivity of data should not affect when I use only equality matchers

You can see that both plans have the same cardinality estimate (which estimate is quite wrong, which would be more concerning to me than the difference is plan choice is.)  But cardinality is not the only thing that goes into a cost estimate.

Comment: Yeah, I checked correlation for both these columns and it was definitely a case here, thanks :)